# Identifying same user accounts using PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a table which has customer details. I want a output table which identifies different customers with same name and zip code and inserts the FIRST_CUSTOMER_ID on first occurrence and set the flag NEW_OLD_FLAG as true, else false using PySpark.

[image]

Thanks!

Results stored in a new table using PySpark

Answer (score 0):

You can use `partitionBy, orderBy` functions using window.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df =spark.createDataFrame([('c1','a1',1234,'1/1/22','01'),('c2','b1',3452,'2/1/22','02'),('c3','c1',12341,'3/1/22','03'),('c4','d1',4562,'3/1/22','04'),('c5','a1',1234,'3/1/22','05'),('c2','b1',3452,'3/1/22','06')],['customer_id','customer_name','customer_zip_code','date','order_id'])
w=Window.partitionBy("customer_name","customer_zip_code").orderBy("order_id")
df1 = df.withColumn("first_customer_id",lag(col("customer_name")).over(w)).\
  withColumn("new_old_flag", when(col("first_customer_id").isNull(),lit(False)).otherwise(lit(True))).select("customer_id","first_Customer_id","date","new_old_flag","order_id")
df1.show(10,False)
#+-----------+-----------------+------+------------+--------+
#|customer_id|first_Customer_id|date  |new_old_flag|order_id|
#+-----------+-----------------+------+------------+--------+
#|c1         |null             |1/1/22|false       |01      |
#|c5         |a1               |3/1/22|true        |05      |
#|c2         |null             |2/1/22|false       |02      |
#|c2         |b1               |3/1/22|true        |06      |
#|c3         |null             |3/1/22|false       |03      |
#|c4         |null             |3/1/22|false       |04      |
#+-----------+-----------------+------+------------+--------+
```

Comment: C2 does not get B1 because it is using the same account C2 where as C1 and C5 are same customers but having different customer ID. I am looking for that scenario only.